# Как динамически собрать значения в массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let costs = [];
    $('.price').each(function( index, item ) {
     let elem = $(item).data('count');
    // costs = costs.push(elem); 
     console.log(elem);
    });
```

```html
<p class="price" data-count="220">220</p>
  <p class="price" data-count="440">440</p>
   <p class="price" data-count="120">120 </p>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let costs = [];
$('.price').each(function(index, item) {
  let elem = $(item).data('count');
  costs.push(elem);
});
console.log(costs);
```

```html
<p class="price" data-count="220">220 грн</p>
<p class="price" data-count="440">440</p>
<p class="price" data-count="120">120 грн</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```